# Error message “value does not fall within the expected range”

Tags: 2013, impersonation, token

I got Error message **“value does not fall within the expected range”** in QA. It is working fine in DEV. I had **increased threshold value from 12 to 20** in QA and working fine. but client does not approved to increase same in prod.

I have also reverted lookup threshold value **back to 12 and add my id in user policy again it worked**. but as we could not add normal user to user policy this will not work again in prod. Then I tried to use run with elevated privileged, it worked fine now in QA but does not worked in prod. what change i need to do in code.

How can I pass app pool account. I am using below, please correct me where I am going wrong.

```
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers[@"domain\abc-18"].UserToken;
 using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(oWeb.Site.ID, token))
                {
                    SPWeb web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb();
```

> I am getting user could not be found.

Comment: have you get resolved this error?

Answer (score 2):

Web.AllUsers Does not cover all the users so you have to check your user in web.Users as well in web.SiteUsers.

**SPUserCollection users = web.Users ;**
SPWeb.Users gets the collection of user objects that are explicitly assigned permissions in the Web site . It will not return users who have access through a group.

**SPUserCollection users = web.AllUsers ;**
SPWeb.AllUsers gets the collection of user objects that represents all users who are either members of the site collection or who have browsed to the site as authenticated members of a domain group in the site.   (note the "browsed to" here... adding a AD group to a site does not add the users to AllUsers immediately... they will not be listed here until they have visited the site at least once.)

**SPUserCollection users = web.SiteUsers ;**
SPWeb.SiteUsers gets the collection of all users that belong to the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code using app pool account, then why don't you try using "[SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" method

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // implementation details omitted
    }
});
```